# why is the result not showing

Tags: java, struts2

Why my output is not coming?

**adder.java**

```
package action;
public class adder {
    int num1,num2,result2;
    public String execute()
    {
        result2=num1+num2;
        return "success";
    }
    public int getNum1() {
        return num1;
    }
    public void setNum1(int num1) {
        this.num1 = num1;
    }
    public int getNum2() {
        return num2;
    }
    public void setNum2(int num2) {
        this.num2 = num2;
    }

}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>letsgo</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <filter>
  <filter-name>f1</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>f1</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<s:form action="adder">
<s:textfield name="num1" label="firstnumber"/>
<s:textfield name="num2" label="secondnumber"/>
<s:submit value="add"/>
</s:form>
```

**MyJsp.jsp**

```
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<b>result is
<s:property value="result2"/>
</b>
<br/> 
<jsp:include page="index.jsp"/>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC 
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
    <struts>
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="adder" class="action.adder" >
    <result name="success">/MyJsp.jsp</result>

    </action>
    </package>
    </struts>
```

The output is `result is`, but the value of result is not being displayed.

Comment: Have you checked the logs for errors?

Comment: @jgitter SEVERE: Error initializing endpoint
java.net.BindException:

Comment: SEVERE: Catalina.start
LifecycleException:

Comment: what is the rest of the message on that Bind Exception ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the Getter for `result2`.

You should also declare the variables `private`.

You are also using the old **FilterDispatcher**: if you are using Struts2 > 2.1.3, remember to change it with the new filter, **StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter**.

Answer (score 0):

It's failing to bind to whatever port you're trying to use for the webserver.  My guess is you forgot to shutdown an instance or it is hanging.

Comment: I don't think so,because when i change in property from result to num1 ,it is showing..there's certainly something about the code

Comment: Then you posted a very old error message in your comment.  Clear the logs, try again, then post the resulting errors.